# IP address formatting in list while removing duplicates (not a duplicate)

Tags: python, string, list, ip, duplicates

## this is not a duplicate question.  I already researched the provided links and the suggestions did not help.  I did open a new question that hopefully provided some clarification.

Let me clarify my questions:
My ultimate goal is to remove the duplicate IP addresses from the list.  I primarily need help with the following issue: I keep running into issues with maintaining the integrity of the IP addresses whenever I try to apply code (itertools, 'for' loops, etc) that removes duplicates from the output.

**In summary:**

1.My output is a tuple containing the matching strings (ip addresses)

2.I convert the tuple to a list of lists - print(hop_list)

3.I index [0] on the list of lists to obtain the IP addresses I need - print(ips)
**Is this where the problem lies?  the output doesn't look like a list of list?**

4.I apply various code solutions to remove duplicate addresses but for some reason I lose the integrity of my IP addresses.

per exscript api docs:
•  anymatch: If a match is found and the regular expression has multiple groups, a tuple containing the matching strings from the groups is returned.

```
def ios_commands(job, host, conn):        #function to execute IOS commands
conn.execute('terminal length 0')
conn.execute('tr {}'.format(DesAddr))
print('The results of the traceroute', repr(conn.response))
for hops in any_match(conn, r"((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)([ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3})"):
    hop_list = list(hops)  #create a list from tuple
    ips = hop_list[0]   #index on targeted addresses
    print(list(uniqify(ips)))  #filter out duplicates
```

**`print(hop_list)       #so far so good, list of lists from tuple`**

['192.33.12.4', '192', '.4', '.', '4']

['192.33.12.4', '192', '.4', '.', '4']

['192.32.0.174', '192', '.174', '.', '174']

['192.32.0.190', '192', '.190', '.', '190']

['192.33.226.225', '192', '.225', '.', '225']

['192.33.226.237', '192', '.237', '.', '237']

['192.33.12.4', '192', '.4', '.', '4']

**Print(ips)  #index first value as that is the address I need**

## I was expecting something like: ['192.33.12.4', '192.33.12.4', etc]

192.33.12.4

192.33.12.4

192.32.0.174

192.32.0.190

192.33.226.225

192.33.226.237

192.33.12.4

**print(list(uniqify(ips)))**

## This is an edited sample output and where I run into a problem with the address format

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '4']

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '4']

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '7', '4']

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '9']

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '6', '5']

['1', '9', '.', '3', '2', '6', '7']

['1', '9 ', '.', '3', '2', '4']

Comment: I found that link by Googling your question's (original) title.

Answer (score 2):

```
set(yourList)
```

Will remove any duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `ips_as_set = set(ips)` to remove duplicate IPs, but that's a batch operation and throws away the order (which might be okay).

If you want to iterate over the IPs in order and remove duplicates on-the-fly, you can do this:

```
from __future__ import print_function


def uniqify(iterable):
    seen = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in seen:
            seen.add(item)
            yield item

for unique_item in uniqify([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8]):
    print(unique_item, end=' ')

print()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  Unfortunately, for both responses: set(yourlist) and def uniqify(iterable) I get results that do not retain the IP address format but breaks it down to individual values.  FYI, I do need to retain the order.  thanks

Comment: I posted [a version of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215911/892383) on [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/892383), since none of the answers there were using a generator.

Comment: @J.Chan, what do you mean it breaks it down to individual values?

Comment: results from uniqify(iterable)1
0
.
3
2
4
1
0
.
3
2
4
1
0
.
3
2
7
4
1
0
.
3
2
9
1
0
.
3
2
6
5
1
0
.
3
2
6
7
1
0
.
3
2
4   set(yourlist) results:set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '4'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '4'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '4', '7'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '9'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '6'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '7', '6'])
set(['.', '1', '0', '3', '2', '4'])

Comment: @J.Chan, what is `iterable`?

Comment: referring to my example code, the iterable would be hop_addresses basically I need to keep the format of my IP addresses intact and in order (referring to output hop_addresses = hops[0]), just removing the duplicates

Comment: @J.Chan, if `hop_addresses` is as shown, in either case, you wouldn't get the output you mentioned.

Comment: `ips = ['192.33.12.4', '192.33.12.4', '192.32.0.174', '192.32.0.190', '192.33.226.225', '192.33.226.237', '192.33.12.4']; print(list(uniqify(ips)))` **results in** `['192.33.12.4', '192.32.0.174', '192.32.0.190', '192.33.226.225', '192.33.226.237']`.

Comment: this is the results I got:hops[0] 
        ips = hops[0]
        print(list(uniqify(ips)))     ['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '4']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '4']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '7', '4']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '9']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '6', '5']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '6', '7']
['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '4']       maybe my existing hops[0] output is off? I'm not sure if it is a list or not.

Comment: @J.Chan, yes, that's definitely the issue, but I'm not sure why the items in `hops[0]` are of the form `['1', '0', '.', '3', '2', '4']`. That shouldn't even work; `set`'s can't hold lists. You're missing something :).